# c# HttpClient does not store some cookies

Tags: c#, http, cookies, request, httpclient

I'm using the HttpClient (System.Net.Http.HttpCient) to send some requests and I'm also using a CookieContainer to hande Cookies. For some Webpages everything works fine, but on some other pages no cookies are stored, although my browser saves the Cookies when I visit the webpage.
Can someone here explain what's the problem.

ceddy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these pages redirect to an other url? Cookies are stored per url and hence it's possible you "loose" a cookie.

To verify the behavior you may set

```
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

and look at the response object about what's going on. If this is really the issue in your case, you can copy the cookies from one url to the other via the CookieContainer.